# Não consigo alterar o centro da rotação de um Tilemap (Unity + C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu estou desenvolvendo um jogo 2D utilizando o *Unity 2018.3.02*.
Estou utilizando *Tilemap* para a construção da fase, porém este Tilemap irá rotacionar. 
Os tiles no Tilemap formam um quadrado, ou seja, os tiles preenchidos são os da borda do quadrado.

Eu tenho um script para o meu tilemap que faz com que esse tilemap rotacione quando clico nas setas para direita ou esquerda do teclado:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
```

O problema é que o meu tilemap rotaciona em torno do primeiro tile do grid(0 em x e 0 em y), e eu gostaria que ele rotacionasse em torno do centro do quadrado formado pelos tiles no tilemap.

Eu consegui fazer o centro do quadrado estar na posição *x=0,y=0*, desta forma, o tilemap rotaciona do jeito planejado. Mas como eu gostaria de usar o grid para obter posições dentro do quadrado, se eu colocar o centro em *x=0,y=0*, seria ruim pois passariam a existirem números negativos em x e y dentro do grid, por isso não seria minha escolha preferida.

**Existe uma forma de alterar o centro da rotação para outra posição que não a inicial(x = 0 e y = 0)?**

Answer (score 1):

Eu não manjo muito de Tilemap, mas já tive muitos problemas com rotação de UI.
O que posso te sugerir é um truque para te ajudar nisso.

Crie um `GameObject`, posicione ele no centro do seu tilemap e jogue o tilemap pra dentro dele. Agora quando você for rotacionar o `GameObject`, seu Tilemap rotacionará de acordo com o centro de rotação do `GameObject` pai.